# Why not display in "ORDER BY DESC" in Cassandra answer?

Tags: cassandra

**Hello, everybody!**
I create keyspace in Cassandra:

```
    CREATE KEYSPACE monitoring WITH replication = {
         'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
         'replication_factor': '1'
    };


    CREATE TABLE monitoring.data (
        number text,
        day timestamp,
        last_day timestamp static,
        ids text static,
        PRIMARY KEY (number, day)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (day DESC);
```

Later i insert data:

```
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('12345678901', '2017-05-26', '2017-05-26', '["1","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('12345678901', '2017-10-26', '2017-10-26', '["1","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('12345678901', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-01', '["1","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('123456AA901', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-01', '["A","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('123456BB901', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-01', '["B","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('123456CC901', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-01', '["C","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('123456DD901', '2017-05-01', '2017-05-01', '["D","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('12345678901', '2017-05-23', '2017-05-23', '["1","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('12345678901', '2018-05-26', '2018-05-26', '["1","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('23456789012', '2017-04-01', '2017-04-01', '["6","2","11"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('34567890123', '2017-03-28', '2017-03-28', '["1","5","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('45678901234', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '["12","2","3"]');
    INSERT INTO monitoring.data (number, day, last_day, ids) VALUES ('56789012345', '2018-01-26', '2018-01-26', '["3","2","1"]');
```

Next i make query:

```
    select distinct number,last_day,ids from monitoring.data WHERE number in ('12345678901','56789012345','45678901234');
```

Why Cassandra answer is and number 45678901234 between 12345678901 and 56789012345?

```
         number        | last_day                 | ids
    -------------+--------------------------+----------------
     12345678901 | 2018-05-25 21:00:00+0000 |  ["1","2","3"]
     45678901234 | 2017-04-02 21:00:00+0000 | ["12","2","3"]
     56789012345 | 2018-01-25 21:00:00+0000 |  ["3","2","1"]
```

How get right answer? Replication factor it's important in this situation? Later i will use LIMIT 10...

Comment: your question is not clear, what is your expected answer ?

Comment: I need order by last_day (DESC)

Comment: last_day or day? If you want by last_day, then this one should be clustering column.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, `number` is your *partition* key, and you can only enforce a sort order at the *clustering* key level.  When filtering with a non-equals clause on your partition key (like `IN`) the order of your results cannot be relied upon.  If you were to remove the `IN` clause you would get the rows returned in the order by their hashed partition keys.  If I make an adjustment to your query to use the `token()` function on `number`, the order of the results makes more sense:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> select distinct number,token(number),last_day,ids 
    FROM data;

number      | system.token(number) | last_day                        | ids
-------------+----------------------+---------------------------------+----------------
 123456BB901 | -7512323826965212800 | 2017-05-01 05:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["B","2","3"]
 123456DD901 | -5242683095224762575 | 2017-05-01 05:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["D","2","3"]
 23456789012 | -2843835925329100734 | 2017-04-01 05:00:00.000000+0000 | ["6","2","11"]
 123456CC901 |   970122905143661162 | 2017-05-01 05:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["C","2","3"]
 45678901234 |  2207499658550692669 | 2017-04-03 05:00:00.000000+0000 | ["12","2","3"]
 12345678901 |  3063849707784841171 | 2018-05-26 05:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["1","2","3"]
 123456AA901 |  4307148681570630627 | 2017-05-01 05:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["A","2","3"]
 56789012345 |  5304329977670805052 | 2018-01-26 06:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["3","2","1"]
 34567890123 |  6079361129233417517 | 2017-03-28 05:00:00.000000+0000 |  ["1","5","3"]

(9 rows)
```

The bottom line, is that you cannot enforce a sort order without an equals condition on the partition key.

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do really isn't a strength of Cassandra.  To get the answer you want, you'll have to look for similarities in the results that you expect, and then design a query table to support it.  But if you're only talking about 10 rows, it might just be easier to sort your results on the application side.

Comment: Can you send script of create table?